# Correct way to integrate Elm with existing web-app service

Tags: go, elm

i have a backend service that I wrote in `Golang`, something like this:

```
func PageA_RequestHandler(ctx *W.Context) {
  // init things
  if is_ajax {
    // handle the API request, render the JSON
    return
  }
  // query the initial rows
  values := M.SX{
    `rows`: model1.GetRows(10),
    `columns`: model1.GetColumns(),
  }
  // render the html
  ctx.Render(`page_a_template`,values)
}
```

then the [template](http://gitlab.com/kokizzu/gokil) file `page_a_template.html` (that loaded and cached at the first time it rendered), is a html file, with content something like this:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  var rows = {/* rows */};
  var cols = [/* columns */]
  new GridBuilder('grid',cols,rows);
</script>
```

Where's:

`{/* rows */}` and `[/* columns */]` are my javascript-friendly template syntax, there are some other syntax like: `/*! bar */` or `#{yay}`

`new GridBuilder` is my custom javascript component that creates something like `datatables.net` or `editablegrid.net`

The question is, if I use `Elm`, what's the correct way to inject the `{/* rows */}` into the compiled html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Html.programWithFlags](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#programWithFlags) (supposing your main module is named `App`):

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  var rows = {/* rows */};
  var cols = [/* columns */];
  var node = document.getElementById('grid');
  Elm.App.embed(node, { rows: rows, cols: cols });
</script>
```

This is the way you can initialize your Elm app with available data just like you are initializing `GridBuilder`.

To be able to read those values, you should create a `Flags` type alias and your `init` function will receive it.

```
type alias Flags =
    { rows : [ ... ]
    , cols : [ ... ]
    }

init : Flags -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
    ...
```

Your `main` function will look like this:

```
main =
    Html.programWithFlags
        { init = init, ... }
```

I highly recommend that you read the [JavaScript Interop](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) section of the [Elm Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org). It explains the `programWithFlags` and other approaches to receive/send data from/to JavaScript.